# Git fast forward not working in Github Actions/Workflows

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a workflow where i auto merge prod branch into master branch  on push in prod branch using Github Actions

Yml file for github action

```
name: Merge Prod -> master

on:
  push:
    branches: [ prod ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Merge prod->master ff_only
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          git config user.name "test"
          git config user.email "test@test.com"
          git fetch origin master
          git fetch origin prod
          git checkout master
          git pull --rebase
          git merge prod --ff-only --allow-unrelated-histories
          git push origin master
```

Logs:

```
Run git config user.name "test"
  git config user.name "test"
  git config user.email "test@test.com"
  git fetch origin master
  git fetch origin prod
  git checkout master
  git pull --rebase
  git merge prod --ff-only --allow-unrelated-histories
  git push origin master
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
From https://github.com/luvk1412/demo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
From https://github.com/luvk1412/demo
 * branch            prod       -> FETCH_HEAD
Switched to a new branch 'master'
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
From https://github.com/luvk1412/demo
Already up to date.
 * [new branch]      f2          -> origin/f2
 * [new branch]      f3          -> origin/f3
 * [new branch]      test_branch -> origin/test_branch
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Example commit : https://github.com/luvk1412/demo/commit/790d824111d0c0c5b28157b9108e7b97b6b6cdc8

Commit generated through PR : https://github.com/luvk1412/demo/pull/38

Test branch : https://github.com/luvk1412/demo

After PR merge into prod, my prod branch fully contains master branch and one extra commit(due to PR), hence fast forward condition is met and fast forward should work, I am not sure what i am missing here.
the fast forward works on my local(if i don't automate this and do manually through local)

Comment: Side note: `--ff-only` and `--allow-unrelated-histories` make no sense in combination. If you want a fast-forward merge, leave out `--allow-unrelated-histories`. The extra option isn't *harmful*, it's just nonsense.

Comment: @torek actually when i was writing this, i had faced an error of unrelated histories and at that time i was not using --ff-only and just didnt remove it after adding --ff-only, i understand what you are saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I have never used these, I suspect that [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout) is the culprit:

> **Only a single commit is fetched by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow. Set fetch-depth: 0 to fetch all history for all branches and tags.** Refer here to learn which commit $GITHUB_SHA points to for different events.

(boldface mine).  With the single commit, Git cannot tell whether the merge would be a fast-forward; with the single branch, Git does not have the necessary branch names.  The extra fetches you run will fix *some* of these problems, but not enough of them.  Setting the fetch depth, as recommended right up front here, would thus fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Script using checkout@V1 which works

```
name: Auto Merge prod->master
on:
  push:
    branches: [ prod ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Merge prod->master
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/<github_user_name>/<repo_name>
        git config user.name "test"
        git config user.email "test@test.com"
        git fetch origin master
        git checkout -b master origin/master
        git merge origin/prod --ff-only
        git push origin master
```